# Eclipse Run As Groovy Script by Default

Tags: eclipse, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'd like to run my Groovy project in Eclipse using a shortcut (CTRL+F11). The trouble is, every time I do so I get a "Select a way to run " dialog, which gives me the choice between Groovy Console, Groovy Script, Java Application.

I've already set a Run Configuration to use Groovy Script, and if I click that Run Configuration under the Run As menu, it just runs.

How can I get my project to execute from a keyboard shortcut without that dialog popping up? I can't imagine ever selecting one of the other options.

Answer (score 1):

I've never been able to get a satisfactory keyboard shortcut for Groovy script runs out of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd>. Instead I use <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> and then press <kbd>G</kbd> when the menu appears.

For debugging I use <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, then <kbd>G</kbd>.

Both are two-stroke, rather than one-stroke, solutions, but neither one forces me to use the mouse or the arrow keys.

Comment: This is what I do as well, but for some explained reason it has stopped working. :(

Answer (score -1):

Under Project>Properties>Java Build Path and then click on Java SE, what ever it may be, click finish.

On the off chance that you deleted your java system library you can o pick up a new one... http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: I apologize if I'm misunderstanding your answer. This sounds more along the lines of something I'd do if my project wasn't running at all.